# log out if connection is lost java

Tags: java, mysql

I'm developing a LAN based application that has a login - logout system. I have a column in the `accounts` table that turns true or false if that user is logged in or not.

I need to execute `logout()` method before losing the connection to database since when the connection is already lost, database cannot be updated anymore.

Replies are GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Hi, Why do you want to logout an user when your backend application has some connectivity problems? Please correct if i understood it wrong

Comment: add the sql statement as part of your logout() method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think that what you are after can be done unless there is a specific set of conditions which happen prior to you losing your connection, thus allowing you to foresee the loss of the connection so that you can take the appropriate action.

You did not provide any information about the architecture of your LAN, so I will be assuming that an application deployed on various machines will attempt to directly query a database situated on the same LAN.

What you can do, is to to deploy another application (from here on denoted as *server*) which sits on top of your database and the other applications connect to it. The purpose of the *server* would be to provide a middle layer between the database and the other applications (which might come in handy should there be any changes to the database) and also to poll the other applications. If the *server* is unable to connect, then, it will set the corresponding values on the database.

Comment: Agree. The middle layer can use techniques like heartbeat check , or ping test to monitor the status of the application server.